# Problema com caracter acentuado no retorno da consulta

Tags: mysql, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, dapper

Eu tenho um banco de dados MySQL com codificação definida como `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Estou usando Dapper para se conectar o base de dados. Quando eu faço uma consulta a determinada tabelas, os caracteres que estão acentuados vem da seguinte forma �, mas os caracteres que não tem acentuação ficar normal.

Por exemplo deveria vir `abraão`, mas está vindo `abra�o`.

**Obervação**: Eu já configurei a [connectionstring](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/specifying-character-set/) para receber UTF-8 (`CharSet=utf8;`).

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <globalization
     fileEncoding="iso-8859-1"
     requestEncoding="iso-8859-1"
     responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"
     culture="pt-BR"
     uiCulture="pt-BR"
  />
</system.web>
```

Comment: E como fica a consulta direto no banco?

Comment: Quando uso _select_ direto do _heidiSql_ o retorno está vindo correto, ou seja, `abraão`.

Comment: Não entendi bem, mas você fala de deixar a connectionstrings dessa forma ?
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword; CharSet=latin1_swedish_ci;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver essa pergunta eu tive que fazer alteração no banco.
**Obervação**: A alteração na codificação no banco, na tabela e nas colunas. Como pode ser visto no código abaixo

```
ALTER DATABASE `banco` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE `banco`.`tabela` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE `banco`.`tabela` MODIFY `Coluna` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```